# Extrair informação de um arquivo.txt

Tags: bash, terminal

Eu tenho um arquivo.txt com a seguinte informação.

```
31.812:9.862 179.52:6.847 315.015:9.135 462.305:6.276
103.875:4.122 176.064:3.593 196.7:4.407 246.599:4.423
```

E preciso extrair essa informação

```
9.862 6.847 9.135 6.276 
4.122 3.593 4.407 4.407
```

( ou seja os valores que estão entre o : e espaço )

Comment: O arquivo `txt` tem como padrão essa formatação?

Answer (score 5):

Tu pode usar o comando `tr` para substituir os `:` por  e depois usar o comando `cut` para selecionar apenas as colunas pares.

Ex.:

```sh
cat arquivo.txt | tr ':' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2,4,6,8
```

**TR**: substitui todos os *dois pontos* por *espaço*

**CUT**:

- **-d**: define o caracter *espaço* como delimitador de campo
- **-f**: Seleciona apenas os campos 2, 4, 6 e 8 que são os números que tu tem interesse.

**arquivo.txt**

```
31.812:9.862 179.52:6.847 315.015:9.135 462.305:6.276
103.875:4.122 176.064:3.593 196.7:4.407 246.599:4.423
```

**output**

```
9.862 6.847 9.135 6.276
4.122 3.593 4.407 4.423
```

Comment: Mas se ele selecionar campos com 6 ele vaia acabar pegando informação que ele não quer, como por exemplo: `103.875` ou não?

Comment: Então @R.Santos, a pergunta não deixa claro se aquele padrão é para todo o arquivo que ele precisa..
Minha solução é rápida mas vale para arquivos com 4 "elementos" por linha.

Como a pergunta não esclarece isso deixei essa resposta como uma alternativa ao Regex.
E como não entendo nada de **awk** foi essa solução que eu achei..

Comment: Certo, só para esclarecer então, questionei ele referente a isso para tirara a dúvida

Comment: Editei a questão para adicionar um exemplo.

Comment: É bom deixar claro que minha solução pega apenas 4 por linha, se tiver mais ignora.

Comment: Certo, por isso questionei ele referente ao padrão do arquivo `txt`

Answer (score 3):

Use expressões regulares para realizar a extração necessária do arquivo  `.txt`, para pegar o que você precisa utilizei a seguinte expressão: **:\d.\d{3}**

[Teste aqui](http://regexr.com/)

Comment: Perfeita citação utilizando as expressões, rápido e prático.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -r 's/[^ ]+:([^ ]+)/\1/g' arquivo.txt
```